# Trying to modify a javascript variable in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I want to change a string in the html and to read it in the javascript and output it to the screen. I want whatever is written in the place of **Select Filter** to be what is written to the screen, how can I do this?

This is the original code which works but doesn't take the string from html:

```
$("#filter ul:eq(1) li:eq(0)").before("<li class='firstItem rounded current'><span class='firstItem'>" + $('#dow').show() +"</span></li>");
```

New HTML:

```
<li id="dow">
 <option data-target='div1'>Select Filter</option>
</li>
```

New Javascript:

```
 var id = $(this).find("#dow").data('target');
    $('#images > div').hide();
    console.log(id);
    $("#filter ul:eq(1) li:eq(0)").before("<li class='firstItem rounded current'><span class='firstItem'>" + $('#dow').show() +"</span></li>");
```

Comment: Why do you have an `<option>` inside of a `<li>`?

Comment: `..." + $('#dow').show() +"...` makes no sense. Did you mean `.text()` instead of `.show()`? `.show()` shows the selected element(s), while `.text()` gets the text content of the selected element(s)... Did you know that jquery has an api documentation? http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 1):

Using `$("#dow").show()` ultimately shows the element and again returns "reference object" to same element, while you want plain markup of that element to be concatenated to the string.

Use `$('#dow').html()` in your concatenation and call `.show()` before that.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for what I needed! This is exactly what I wanted, you saved me quite a headache, cheers.